# proving the symmetric and transitive properties of an equivalence relation

Tags: group-theory

Let $S$ be a non-empty set, $A$ be the set of all functions from $S$ to $S$, and $B$ be the set of all bijective functions from $S$ to $S$. Define the following relation on A:

$$f \sim g \iff \exists h \in B \mid fh=g$$

where $fh$ is the composition of $f$ and $h$. Is this an equivalence relation on $A$?

This is what I have so far:

$ah=a ⇒  a^{-1} ah=a^{-1} a ⇒ eh=e⇒ h=e$ and $e \in B$ therfore $a \sim a$
Because $e$ is the identity element and all sets have an identity element, therefore it is reflexive.

$$ah=b ⇒ a^{-1} ah=a^{-1} b⇒ eh=a^{-1} b⇒ h=a^{-1} b$$
$$bh=a⇒ b^{-1} bh=b^{-1} a⇒ eh=b^{-1} a⇒ h=b^{-1} a$$
But I do not know how to show that since $a \sim b$ then $b \sim a$. I think I have a start but I’m not sure how to show this.

I am also not sure how to show that it is transitive because I keep solving for h but don’t know how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For symmetry show that $ah=b$ implies $bh^{-1}=a$ .

For transitivity show that $ah_1=b$ and $bh_2=c$ implies $ah=c$ where $h=h_1 h_2$.

Comment: I see! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that says that $a$ is bijective or that $a^{-1}$ exists.

But $h$ is bijective and $h^{-1}$ exists

Reflexive $a\sim a$

Let $h$ be the identity function.

Symmetric $a\sim b \implies b\sim a$

There exists an $h$ such that $a\circ h = b$

$b\circ h^{-1} = a$

Transitive $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c \implies a\sim c$

$a\circ h = b\\
b\circ g = c\\
a\circ (h\circ g) = c$

The composition of two bijections is a bijection.